# Java: Refresh my jsp with the servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i'm working on my jsp page, and i have a link with 2 parameters:
shop.jsp:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/boutique?achat=${module.id}&token=${module.token}" />" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Oui</a>
```

So i have 2 if in my servlet, to work on the two parameters:
shop.java:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    httpServletRequest.setAttribute("page", "boutique");
    HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(true);
    int tokens = moduleDAO.getTokens(session.getAttribute("sessionPlayer"));
    List<Module> modules = moduleDAO.select();
    httpServletRequest.setAttribute("modules", modules);
    httpServletRequest.setAttribute("tokens", tokens);

    if(httpServletRequest.getParameter("achat") != null)
    {
        inventoryDAO.addInventory(session.getAttribute("sessionPlayer"), Integer.parseInt(httpServletRequest.getParameter("achat")));
    }

    if(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token") != null)
    {
        inventoryDAO.changeToken(session.getAttribute("sessionPlayer"), Integer.parseInt(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token"))); 
    }

    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/shop.jsp").forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}
```

But i want to refresh my page after clicked on the lick with the 2 parameters because in my shop.jsp page i have a value: ${tokens}, which it doesn't refresh, because when i click on the link i still on th eurl with the 2 parameters.

So how i can refresh the page, after clicking on the link ?

Thanks!

I did:

```
if(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token") != null)
{
    inventoryDAO.changeToken(session.getAttribute("sessionPlayer"), Integer.parseInt(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token"))); 
    String referer = httpServletResponse.getHeader("/WEB-INF/boutique.jsp");
    httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(referer);
}

getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/shop.jsp").forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
```

But i get an error: Cant use forward after response getted

Comment: @Nivedita i want to refresh after the if

Comment: I think you can use use Referer: `String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
   
     response.sendRedirect(referer);`

Comment: @Nivedita I did:

if(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token") != null)
  {
   inventoryDAO.changeToken(session.getAttribute("sessionPlayer"), Integer.parseInt(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token"))); 
   String referer = httpServletResponse.getHeader("/WEB-INF/boutique.jsp");
   httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(referer);
  }
  
  getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/shop.jsp").forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

Error: Cant use forward after response getted

Comment: Can you update this in the question? It's not clear in the comment.

Comment: Maybe you can write the forward statement in the else part. You don't want to refresh and forward at the same time?

Comment: @Nivedita 

`
  getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/boutique.jsp").forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);`

It' for display my page

Comment: Try writing just getHeader("referer"); instead of getHeader("/WEB-INF/boutique.jsp");

Comment: Same error with:
`  if(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token") != null)
  {
   inventoryDAO.changeToken(session.getAttribute("sessionPlayer"), Integer.parseInt(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token"))); 
   String referer = httpServletResponse.getHeader("referer");
   httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(referer);
  }`

Comment: It should be `String referer = httpServletRequest.getHeader("/WEB-INF/boutique.jsp");` not `String referer = httpServletResponse.getHeader("/WEB-INF/boutique.jsp");`

Comment: @Nivedita

Same error with:
`  if(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token") != null)
  {
   inventoryDAO.changeToken(session.getAttribute("sessionPlayer"), Integer.parseInt(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token"))); 
   String referer = httpServletRequest.getHeader("/WEB-INF/boutique.jsp");
   httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(referer);
  }`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211497/servlet-cannot-forward-after-response-has-been-committed

Comment: @Nivedita

Thanks, but i found an anoher question on stackoverflow, and i added a return;:
`  if(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token") != null)
  {
   inventoryDAO.changeToken(session.getAttribute("sessionPlayer"), Integer.parseInt(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token"))); 
   httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/galactium/boutique");
         return;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I found an anoher question on stackoverflow, and i added a return;:

```
if(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token") != null) {
inventoryDAO.changeToken(session.getAttribute("sessionPlayer"), Integer.parseInt(httpServletRequest.getParameter("token")));
httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/galactium/boutique");
return;
}
```